IMAP on Outlook Hotmail takes many attempts (LOGIN failed) to authenticate
I have this code to authenticate/login to hotmail.com via IMAP. I have enabled app password for hotmail/outlook. The only problem is authentication fails with "Login failed" for first 5-10 attempts and finally succeeds with the same app password. I am not able to debug why this happens.
import logging
import imaplib
import sys

# Your email credentials
email_user = "user1@hotmail.com"  
email_pass = "APPPASSWORD"      
IMAPserver = "outlook.office365.com"
ImapPort = 993

# Configure logging to write to both file and console
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Console handler
log_handler_console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_handler_console.setFormatter(log_formatter)

# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(log_handler_console)

def connect_to_server(server, port):
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
        logging.info(f"Connected to the email server {server}.")
        return mail
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
        logging.error(f"Connection failed: {str(e)}")
        return None
        
def login_with_retries(server, port, email_user, email_pass, max_retries=30, retry_delay=5):
    for attempt in range(max_retries):
        mail = connect_to_server(server, port)
        if mail is None:
            logging.error(f"Retrying connection in {retry_delay} seconds...")
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
            continue
        try:
            
            mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
            logging.info(f"Logged into the email account {email_user}.")
            return mail  # Return the mail object if login is successful
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
            logging.error(f"LOGIN failed on attempt {attempt + 1} of {max_retries} (Retry in {retry_delay} seconds). Error: {str(e)}")
            mail.logout()  # Ensure proper logout before retrying connection
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
    logging.error("All login attempts failed. Check your email credentials and settings.")
    return None  # Return False if all attempts fail

try: 
    # Connect to server
    mail = login_with_retries(IMAPserver, ImapPort, email_user, email_pass)
    
    if mail is None:
        # Handle login failure
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to IMAP login after multiple attempts.")

    # Select mailbox
    mail.select("inbox")
    logging.info("Mailbox inbox folder selected.")

except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    #print(f"An IMAP error occurred: {e}")
    logging.error(f"An IMAP error occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
    wait_with_timeout(sleepError)
    sys.exit(1)

except Exception as e:
    #print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
    wait_with_timeout(sleepError)
    sys.exit(1)

When I run the code, I see after multiple attempts it succeeds. Not sure why?
Here is the log:
2024-08-01 14:04:49 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:04:51 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 1 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:04:56 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:04:57 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 2 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:02 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:03 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 3 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:09 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:10 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 4 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:15 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:16 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 5 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:21 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:23 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 6 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:28 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:29 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 7 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:35 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:36 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 8 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-08-01 14:05:41 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:42 - INFO - Logged into the email account user1@hotmail.com.
2024-08-01 14:05:44 - INFO - Mailbox inbox folder selected.


I'm assuming your example using basic auth doesn't work anymore, but this was a known defect in Microsoft's IMAP server: "Users [using] Basic Authentication may experience recurring password prompts" - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-and-other-apps-are-unable-to-connect-to-outlook-com-when-using-basic-authentication-f4202ebf-89c6-4a8a-bec3-3d60cf7deaef
